# how do i display the user nickname instead of the ID on the page profile

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, friendly-url

i'm just a beginner and my question is:

some sites uses **profiles php** to get display the **users Profile** like this example here: **www.site.come/profile.php?id=11** ( this link for example will take us to the user **Pedro's Profile**) ...
MY Problem is how to change this methode by using this one :  (**www.site.com/Pedro**)

For now i know just the First Methode by using the **ID=Some-Number**
i think the second methode is the best... Atleast for the security Part Section..

finally anny suggestion will be well appreciated and sorry for my first stupid question.

Comment: it's called a mod rewrite. Consult the duplicate.

Comment: plz may i get a little example that can guide more ..